# How to "completely" delete all nodes in a linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I got curious about how pointers and deleting pointers worked in C++ so I set up an experiment. I made a very simple singly linked list and the following recursive function that deletes all nodes in a list:

```
void deleteList(Node *node) {
    if (!node)
        return;
    deleteList(node->next);
    cout << "deleting node " << node->data << endl;
    delete node;
    node = nullptr;
}
```

I suppose that this successfully deletes all nodes in a list. However, after calling this function in main, I check to see if the head node still exists:

```
List list;
// appending a bunch of numbers to the list...
list.deleteList(list.head);
if (list.head) 
    cout << true;
```

this will print 1 to the console, meaning that the head does indeed still exist. I would expect the head, and all other nodes after it, to be null and hence that the if condition fails, since setting pointers to null is the last thing I do in the recursive function. So why does the program report that the head still exists?

edit: changed List list(); to List list;

Comment: `List list();` isn't what you think. [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: Yes, I actually have two constructors in my experiment. The one in my example above calls the other constructor which initializes values like 0 for size and a new empty head node.

Comment: The statement does not call constructor at all. It is declaration of a function `list` whose return type is `List`. For object initialization,`()` needs to be removed.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right. Don't know what I was thinking there for a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You freed the memory, but the assignment to `nullptr` only affected the copy of the pointer passed to the function, not the original pointer in the caller.

If you declared the function as receiving the pointer by reference:

```
void deleteList(Node *&node) {
```

then the assignment of `node = nullptr;` would affect the caller as well.

<s>Mind you, since you tagged this C++11, it's usually much simpler to just define the linked list as a series of `std::unique_ptr<Node>`s in the forward direction (raw pointers in the reverse direction if it's bidirectional to avoid reference cycles), so you can avoid the need for a special deleter function, and just set the head pointer to `nullptr` and let C++ do the work of cascading the deletion.</s>

**Edit**: There is a flaw to letting `std::unique_ptr` do the work; as pointed out in the comments, this means the list size is effectively limited by the stack, and too large lists will cause stack overflow when you delete them. So explicitly clearing one by one (the simplest approach being to implement popping properly, and have clearing simply be popping until `head` is converted to a `nullptr` by the `popleft` method) would be safer. I left the original suggestion in place for posterity, so this explanation makes sense.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the clarification. I thought that pointers were always passed by reference.

This is the first time I'm hearing about unique pointers (if that's what they're called?). I will need to learn more about these

Comment: @MannyKim: Yup, [unique pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Pointers are funny, because the pointer itself is passed by value; both pointers initially reference the same memory, but changing the pointer in the callee does not affect the caller, it's only changes to the data pointed to (which includes the effects of freeing memory at that location; don't dereference a pointer you know was freed by another function) that are visible.

Comment: just to be clear, "freed a pointer" refers to "delete node" and "dereference a pointer" refers to "node = nullptr", is that correct? And thank you for the extra details, it really makes it a little easier to understand pointers

Comment: *(raw pointers in the reverse direction if it's bidirectional to avoid reference cycles)* -- You can also use [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in this case.

Comment: @vsoftco: That's not a bad idea, though you'd need to use slightly higher overhead `std::shared_ptr`s in the forward direction in that case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ohh yes, forgot that you cannot use it with a `unique_ptr`. I guess the future [`observer_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) will be the most suitable here.

Comment: @MannyKim: "freed" and "deleted" are equivalent; in C, you use the `free` function, in C++ you use the `delete` keyword (although ideally, you use smart pointers like `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` to avoid needing to use `delete` explicitly). Dereference a pointer means actually using it to look up data, using `*` or `->`. Deleting actually effectively dereferences a pointer too (deleting it twice is a serious error). Assigning `nullptr` neither deletes/frees nor deferences for dumb pointers, but for unique pointers, it's equivalent to both deleting and clearing the pointer at once.

Comment: Letting C++ do the work of cascading deletion of recursive data structures can lead to stack overflow.

Comment: @ConstantinBaranov: Mmm... good point. Forgot about that; for toy problems, not an issue, but for a true general purpose data structure you wouldn't want to be constrained by the stack's maximum size. This is what I get for letting my skills in reimplementing basic containers lapse by, you know, using the stuff the STL gives me for free. :-) I've updated my answer to discourage this.